# When is it not safe to turn off the __STRICT_ANSI__ flag?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I am creating an application which uses the Apple GLKit headers. In this library, they turn off unions if __STRICT_ANSI__ is defined. I know how to undefined this via compiler flag, but I hate to do this without knowing why they had this in there, and under what circumstances this matters?

Code From Apple's source:

```
#if defined(__STRICT_ANSI__)
struct _GLKVector4
{
    float v[4];
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef struct _GLKVector4 GLKVector4;  
#else
union _GLKVector4
{
    struct { float x, y, z, w; };
    struct { float r, g, b, a; };
    struct { float s, t, p, q; };
    float v[4];
} __attribute__((aligned(16)));
typedef union _GLKVector4 GLKVector4;
#endif
```

Comment: Can you show a bit of the code in the conditional?

Comment: Type punning (e.g. storing to `v[0]` and reading from `x` ) used to be implementaton-defined.

Comment: If we consider the C++ tags: Union type punning is not supported by *any* C++ standard. On the other hand, neither is this attribute syntax. So, in practice, the code is portable to compilers where it works. Strict or not. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of protections are used on code that is using non standard constructs or specific to some development tools. The same thing is present in Microsoft headers for exactly the same issue: nameless structures/unions.

In your specific case the definition uses nameless structures that where not allowed before C11 standard, where a standard macro `__STDC_VERSION__` is defined with value `201112L` to indicate that C11 support is available.

This seems just a precaution for old compilers. If you try to compile with a pre-C11 you'll get an error.

The correct definition should be:

```
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ < 201112L)
```

Note the comparison for `__STDC_VERSION__` less than `201112L` in the supposition that newer standard will keep support for nameless structures/unions.

Anyway some care must always be taken before removing conditional compilations when we haven't correctly identified the reason for which they are there.

Answer (score 3):

I think they're misusing the `__STRICT_ANSI__` macro. It it not defined by any standard, but instead just by GCC and compatible compilers to indicate that you used `-std=c99`/`-std=c11`/etc., in which case the system headers by default should not pollute the namespace with anything not allowed by the C standard.

If the library is using unions in some hackish way that's not actually valid C (e.g. has undefined behavior) but that's permitted by GCC, they should not be using `#ifndef __STRICT_ANSI__` but instead `#ifdef __GNUC__`.

In any case, it's hard to know for sure what to tell you without seeing the actual code, but I'm pretty sure you can just ignore this.

Comment: Thanks for the great information! I clarified my question as it became obvious that this is very case dependent. I also doubted such a core library from Apple would have such a flag miss-match.